# How to change resolution past 1024x762?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

So my Windows 8.1 broke on me and I have no way to repair it without a disc. I just switched to the latest stable Ubuntu last night until I can get an ISO to repair my Windows 8. I'm curious why my res is locked at 1024x762. I need a higher resolution because this is just hard to use. I'm very new to Linux and I'd like to be able to have the same res that I had on Windows (1280x1024) not a big difference but I like a wider screen.

I tried various xrandr commands from all around here and Linux forums but I get an error about gamma output. I've looked the error up and it makes no sense on how to fix it

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

I have a GTX 750 and I think I have the NVIDIA drivers installed, I'm not very sure how to verify the installation of the driver, I did the command that lists your devices and NVIDIA came up so I think it's installed.

Comment: There are tools that exist that will allow you to extract your license key in order to download a [Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) .ISO file from Microsoft.  In order to use resolutions past 1024x762 you need to install the Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm aware of how to get the ISO, I'm more curious about resolution. Apparently I haven't installed the driver correctly because I can't change my resolution through settings or xrandr

Comment: You have not indicate what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: The version is 14.4 lts

Comment: System Settings -> Screen display will show in the Resolution drop-down only those settings which your graphics card/monitor will support. `xrandr` with the `--panning` option will allow you to set almost any resolution you want, with your current display being a pannable window into a larger, virtual display. I've always got good support from the Ubuntu graphics drivers and never needed proprietary ones. Do you get the same reduction in resolution when you run the LiveCD?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is usually due to the correct drivers not being installed.

To resolve this, simply launch the dash and search for "driver". Then click the application named "Additional Drivers". It will lauch a dialog box that will give you an option for what driver to use.

I would recommend you stay with the Nvidia Proprietary drivers as they will give you the best performance from the card.